# Replacement for JAXMServlet?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxm

I am maintaining an application that has classes (written in 2005) that extend *javax.xml.messaging.JAXMServlet*. While upgrading to a new app server that implements the latest J2EE standards, I discovered that *JAXMServlet* was removed in JWSDP 2.0 (Java Web Services Developer Pack), according to [this question](http://www.javaforums.info/java-programming-archive/jaxm-demise-jwsdp-and-t3283.html) (and apparently JWSDP itself has been [deprecated](http://java.sun.com/webservices/downloads/previous/index.jsp) too). The code it relies on has not significantly changed since it was written, and is part of a large-ish existing production system where this code is already tested and debugged, so I am reluctant to rewrite the classes from scratch due to the regression testing impact.

Is there an 'easy' substitution for this class? Although Google has a lot of examples of using this code (dated from around 2003-2004), it is surprisingly mute about replacing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, found some replacement code at [http://www.java.happycodings.com/Java%5fUtil%5fPackage/code23.html](http://www.java.happycodings.com/Java_Util_Package/code23.html):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.soap.AttachmentPart;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeader;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

public class SaajUtils {
    /**
    * extract the MIME header information from within the HTTP Request
    * @param req the http request
    * @return MimeHeaders as defined within the SAAJ API
    */
    public static MimeHeaders getHeaders( HttpServletRequest req ) {
      Enumeration<String> en = req.getHeaderNames();
      MimeHeaders headers = new MimeHeaders();

      while( en.hasMoreElements() ) {
        String headerName = (String) en.nextElement();
        String headerValue = req.getHeader( headerName );

        StringTokenizer values = new StringTokenizer( headerValue, "," );
        while( values.hasMoreTokens() ) {
          headers.addHeader( headerName, values.nextToken().trim() );
        }
      }
      return headers;
    }

    /**
     * stuff the MIME headers into the HTTP response
     * @param headers the SAAJ MIME headers
     * @param res the Http servlet response
     */
    public static void putHeaders( MimeHeaders headers, HttpServletResponse res ) {
        for( Iterator<MimeHeader> it = headers.getAllHeaders(); it.hasNext(); ) {
          MimeHeader header = it.next();
          String[] values = headers.getHeader( header.getName() );
          if( values.length == 1 ) {
            res.setHeader( header.getName(), header.getValue() );
          }
          else {
            StringBuffer concat = new StringBuffer();
            for( int i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ) {
              if( i != 0 ) {
                concat.append( ',' );
              }
              concat.append( values[i] );
          }
          res.setHeader( header.getName(), concat.toString() );
        }
      }
    }

    public static void attachBytes( SOAPMessage soapMessage, byte[] theBytes, String contentType )
    throws SOAPException {
      AttachmentPart attachment = soapMessage.createAttachmentPart();
      attachment.setContent( new ByteArrayInputStream( theBytes ), contentType );
      soapMessage.addAttachmentPart( attachment );
    }

    public static void attachUrlContents( SOAPMessage soapMessage, String urlLocation, String contentType )
    throws SOAPException, MalformedURLException {
      URL url = new URL( urlLocation );
      AttachmentPart attachment = soapMessage.createAttachmentPart( new DataHandler( url ) );
      attachment.setContentType( contentType );
      soapMessage.addAttachmentPart( attachment );
    }

    public static String getAttachmentReport( SOAPMessage soapMessage ) throws SOAPException {
      int numOfAttachments = soapMessage.countAttachments();
      Iterator<AttachmentPart> attachments = soapMessage.getAttachments();

      StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer( "Number of attachments: " );
      buf.append( numOfAttachments );

      while( attachments.hasNext() ) {
        buf.append( "\n--------------------------------------------\n" );
        AttachmentPart attachment = attachments.next();
        buf.append( "\nContent Location: " + attachment.getContentLocation() );
        buf.append( "\nContent Id: " + attachment.getContentId() );
        buf.append( "\nContent Size: " + attachment.getSize() );
        buf.append( "\nContent Type: " + attachment.getContentType() );
      }

      return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why replace it? Why not find the relevant libraries and use them?

http://java.sun.com/webservices/downloads/previous/webservicespack.jsp

Comment: I believe this is the new URL: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/webservicespack-jsp-140788.html